# Performance : Vector vs ArrayBuffer vs Array

Tags: scala, performance, vector, arraybuffer

Scala 2.11.4 -
While trying to solve this problem ["Sliding Window Maximum"](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/), I wrote this code :

```
def slidingMaximum(A: Array[Int], B: Int): Array[Int]  = {
    var ans = Vector[Int]() 
    var vectorQ = Vector[Int]()
    
    for (i <- 0 to A.length-1) {
        if (vectorQ.isEmpty) {
            vectorQ = vectorQ :+ i   
        }else{
            while (!vectorQ.isEmpty && A(vectorQ.last) <= A(i)) 
                vectorQ = vectorQ.dropRight(1)
            
            while (!vectorQ.isEmpty && (vectorQ.head <= i-B)) 
                vectorQ = vectorQ.drop(1)
            
            vectorQ = vectorQ :+ i
        }
        if (i+1 >= B) ans = ans :+ A(vectorQ.head);
    }
    return ans.toArray;
}
```

Since, I am a beginner in Scala Language, I used this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618659/does-scala-have-double-side-queue-similar-to-java-deque-or-python-deque) for using `Vector` as Deque. When I tried replacing `Vector` type with `Array` or `ArrayBuffer`, the test cases failed for poor time complexity. Why can't we have `var ans = ArrayBuffer[Int]()` or `var ans = Array[Int]()` when it is mostly involved in append operation using `:+`?

What makes `Vector` really standout?

Comment: Here's a blog post about [benchmarking Scala collections](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html) that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be sure without some flame graph showing where all that time is spent but I would suspect several things:

- you are not mutating a copy, but assigning to `var` a modified copy
- immutable `Vector` uses structural sharing to limit the cost of a single change
- copy of `Array` or `ArrayBuffer` requires copying a whole array - you would have much better performance if you just mutated the array in place

So I would expect the performance to be:

- best for mutating array in place (potentially wrapped in ArrayList or other mutable vector implementation)
- worse but still acceptable for immutable vector (because of structural sharing)
- worst for copying whole array/ArrayBuffer on each change

Answer (score 2):

You can find the following post: [Vector or MutableList / ListBuffer for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059155/2359227) which answers your question as described in the title.

Having said that, you can implement this problem really easily in Scala. Assuming we have the following vector:

```
val v = Vector(1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7)
```

The following will provide what you are looking for, with good performance:

```
v.sliding(3).map(_.max)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/GRmFfI0PQHWNbDbhARdg1Q).

Comment: Thanks. That is so short and elegant, **but** I won't be so sure about its runtime complexity because there is some optimisation in my code. For mine it is `O(N)`. Could it be `O(N*B)` for your code where `B` is the length of the sliding window?

Comment: @SauravSahu, you are right about the complexity. But it is worth measuring the total time, since a lot is being saved here because of the immutability.